# How do I get Windows 7 to highlight my icons again?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons, aero, highlighting

You know when your mouse goes over a desktop icon in Windows 7, a small box appears around it highlighting it? It's gone on my computer. And it annoys me because usually when I'm waiting for a program to start I play around by mousing over all my desktop icons.

Can someone tell me how to get that hover/selection box back?

Comment: Has Aero switched off? It does sometimes when a legacy app runs and Windows automatically switches you to Windows Basic theme

Answer (score 1):

The box around the icon shows when you have "Visual Styles" enabled, e.g. "Aero". The translucent selection rectangle (that appears when you drag over icons with your mouse pressed) is an option under Performance Options.

In order to find these settings, go to **System** (under **System and Security** in the **Control Panel**), then click **Advanced System Settings** and click **Settings…** under **Performance**. Make sure both **Show translucent selection rectangle** and **Use visual styles on windows and buttons** are checked.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was search adujst in start, and click on adjust the appearance and performance of Windows. Set to best performance. wait until it is done, then click on Let windows choose what's best. It came back for me, I hope it works.